# ad serving has been disabled to your application

Tags: android, admob, adsense

I received a mail from Admob saying that **"ad serving has been disabled to your application."**
Please let me know my package name will be blocked or not
I have two possible solution:
1.Should I change the ad unit ID and update my App or 
2.Should I change my package name
What should I do because I know Google will not start ad services after appeal.
Please Reply.

Comment: If you changed whatever the violation you did, then submit the appeal form with all the details. and if they agree that you changed the content whatever they asked, then automatically they will enable your ads.

Comment: for my another App I changed all contents but they didn't enable ads, please let me know changing Ad Unit is a solution or not.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not a programming issue.

Answer (score -1):

First check that main why the admob ads has disable to your app. solve that issue first then you appeal. Otherwise you try other publisher.. they will serve the ads on your app.